# Some Firebase function labels set to "-" glitch

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been deploying firebase functions for over 2 years running the firebase deploy script `firebase deploy --only functions` without issue. I am using firebase version `12.7` and node v16. For some reason, a deployment I just did reset a bunch of `functionName` labels to `-`, so where in the cloud logs I would typically see the function name, 80% of the functions I just deployed had their resource functionName label set to `-` (full hover text `resource.labels.functionName:-`)

I tried redeploying and it didn't fix it.

Has anyone else experienced this? Have you fixed it? Is there a way to manually fix it and hope it stays fixed?

PS: I recall seeing this in the past, but it resolved in a few logs. This time it's not resolving.

[image]

Comment: It resolved on its own days later. Very bizarre